# Debugging COM callable wrapper

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, debugging, mfc

In my WPF application, I have added a reference to a COM callable wrapper dll. This dll basically acts as an interface between my WPF application(.exe) and a legacy .exe (MF) project.

I have made solution of legacy code including COM callable wrapper, legacy project (.exe) and another solution contiainig the WPF applciation.

When Legacy code's exe is lauchned through debugging everything works great. But when I run the Legacy exe. from outside Visual Studio (not debugging it), then my WPF application fails to connect to the legacy's exe. through COM callable wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to know the problem. So basically when I debug my legacy, the exe is launched from the debug folder. So when WPF tries to connect to the legacy's exe that is the debug path that I have given.

But when I launch Legacy exe without debug that is launched from a different location, due to which my WPF app does not connect to it.